# The argument type 'Future<List<Explore>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<List<Explore>>?'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to the concept of Flutter `FutureBuilder` and am struggling to why the `FutureBuilder<List<explore>>` in the code-snippet could be null, how could I treat this case?

Usage snippet:

```
class Explore extends StatelessWidget {
  const Explore({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Explore>>(
        future: FirestoreService().getExplore(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const LoadingScreen();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
                child: ErrorMessage(message: snapshot.error.toString()));
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var themes = snapshot.data!;
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent.shade700,
                title: const Text('Explore'),
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.circleUser,
                      color: Colors.pink.shade200,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              body: GridView.count(
                primary: false,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                children: themes.map((topic) => Text(topic.)).toList(),
              ),
              bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(),
            );
          } else {
            return const Text('No themes found. Contact the developer.');
          }
        });
```

Firestore snippet where I define the getExplore() function:

```
class FirestoreService {
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  Future<List<Explore>> getExplore() async {
    var ref = _db.collection('explore');
    var snapshot = await ref.get();
    var data = snapshot.docs.map((s) => s.data());
    var themes = data.map((d) => Explore.fromJson(d));
    return themes.toList();
  }
}
```

I was not able to come up with any kind of solution.

Comment: What exact line raises this error?

Comment: At which line you will get error/warning suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first of all widget name and model name not be same.
you might be facing the issue.

and for above issue you just change

```
builder: (context, snapshot)
```

to

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Explore>> snapshot)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the following error:

> The argument type 'Future<List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<List>?'

Because the `FutureBuilder` in your code expects a *nullable* `Future<List<Explore>>?`, see the question mark, as its future parameter, but your `getExplore()` function returns a *non-nullable* `Future<List<Explore>>`, no question mark.

To solve this, you should make sure that the `getExplore()` function returns a *nullable* `Future<List<Explore>>?`. Please see below how you can modify your `getExplore()` function to return a *nullable* future:

```
class FirestoreService {
  Future<List<Explore>> getExplore() async {
    try {
      var ref = _db.collection('explore');
      var snapshot = await ref.get();
      var data = snapshot.docs.map((s) => s.data());
      var themes = data.map((d) => Explore.fromJson(d));
      return themes.toList();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error fetching explore data: $e");
      return null;  //
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;
Just rename the Widgets name from `Explore` to something else, maybe `ExploreWidget`.

---

Explanation:
Here the `FutureBuilder` is getting confused with your return types. 
Note that your return type is `List<Explore>` and the widgets name is also `Explore`.

I suppose the `FirestoreService` will be in a separate file and the `Explore` it is returning is a Data Class, not a widget.

But in the line

```
return FutureBuilder<List<Explore>>(
```

the builder thinks you are returning the "Explore Widget", but while calling `FirestoreService().getExplore()`, you are in effect returning the "Explore Data Class", and hence the error.

This is due to the import conflicts. 
If you don't want to rename the widget, and you want both to be named `Explore`, then consider importing using `as` keyword. [refer this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34395#issuecomment-501742438)